# Javascript hashtag regex extract portlet name and page number

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello in my website I user hash-tags in the urls like `#vehicle-list-page-25`. What I would like to do is extract the `vehicle-list-page` in one string and `25` in another. How can I accomplish this?

I was testing regex here:

https://www.debuggex.com/

and managed to create this one:

`^[#][-A-Za-z]+[0-9]+$`

which matches the hashtag but I don't know hwo can I remove the parts that I don't need with the use of regex, since I dont have experience with them.
I could implement this with `.substr()` and `.search()` but I suppose there is a better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
var m = '#vehicle-list-page-25'.match(/^#(.+?)-(\d+)$/);
```

Then use `m[1]` and `m[2]` for your values.

```
console.log(m[1]); // vehicle-list-page
console.log(m[2]); // 25
```